# What is cypher's Backus-Naur Form?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, bnf

I'm wondering if Cypher (Neo4j query language) has a Backus-Naur Form.

If so, where can I find it? If it doesn't, could you guess one?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a separate grammar that's published for the language, but you can get what you need [from this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/community/cypher/cypher-compiler-2.3/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_3/parser/Clauses.scala).

Internally, neo4j uses a package called [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) to do its parsing of cypher.  In the cypher compiler software package, generally in `/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_3/parser/` you'll find a file called `Clauses.scala` which essentially implements the cypher grammar in Scala.

To take a really simple example, here's the definition of the `LIMIT` clause:

```
  private def Limit: Rule1[ast.Limit] = rule("LIMIT") {
    group(keyword("LIMIT") ~~ (UnsignedIntegerLiteral | Parameter)) ~~>> (ast.Limit(_))
  }
```

Simple enough, a `LIMIT` clause is the keyword `LIMIT` followed by an unsigned integer literal or parameter.

Note that one of the more complicated bits of the syntax is in `Patterns.scala` where you see what constitutes a graph pattern.  Other resources like that are included by reference in `Clauses.scala`.

I don't have a lot of experience with parboiled, it's quite possible that given this definition of the grammer, parboiled could generate a grammar in whatever syntax you might like.